# Prove that a matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-matrices

*Show that the matrix*

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \ldots & \frac{1}{n}\\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \ldots & \frac{1}{n+1}\\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ \frac{1}{n} &\frac{1}{n+1} &\ldots &\frac{1}{2n-1} \end{bmatrix}$

*is invertible and* $A^{-1}$ *has integer entries.*

This problem appeared in Chapter one of my linear algebra textbook so I assume nothing more is required to prove it than elementary row operations. I've been staring at it for a while and considered small values of $n$ but there doesn't seem to be a clever way of easily reducing it to the identity matrix. Could someone give me a hint or a poke in the right direction rather than a full solution as I'm still hoping to work it out myself.

Comment: Very nice situation. Today I asked the same question and got this page as a link. I saw the question many times previously but today I became very much interested to know the solution. Many student has faced the same several times.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your linear algebra textbook is Kenneth Hoffmann and Ray Kunze's Linear Algebra book then I was in the same situation you're right now a few years ago, but I was adviced at the moment that this particular exercise wasn't as easy as one might expect at first.

The matrix you have is called the [Hilbert matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) and the question you have was already asked a couple of times in math overflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47561/deriving-inverse-of-hilbert-matrix) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60000/elementary-proof-that-the-hilbert-matrix-is-invertible-with-integer-entries-clos). They have excellent answers so I will just point you to them.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Hoffman and Kunze and according to the comments in your second link, it seems that a simple proof is possible with the concept of a determinants, but they're not presented yet in Hoffman and Kunze. It's nice to know what the matrix is called though!

Comment: Thanks, those two links were very helpful. Also, it's nice to know what the matrix is called!

Comment: @Herman Chau I'm glad it helped you. And yes, it is good to know that the matrix has a name, since Hoffmann and Kunze's book didn't say anything about it.

Comment: @AdriánBarquero And did you find any solution just using the tools provided for the first exercise? I'm curious.