# Some questions about Hilbert matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-matrices

This Exercise $12$ page $27$ from Hoffman and Kunze's book *Linear Algebra*.

> The result o Example $16$ suggests that perhaps the matrix
>
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \ldots & \frac{1}{n}\\
>  \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \ldots & \frac{1}{n+1}\\ \vdots & \vdots &
>  & \vdots \\ \frac{1}{n} &\frac{1}{n+1} &\ldots &\frac{1}{2n-1}
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> is invertible and $A^{-1}$ has integer entries. Can you prove that?

I will copy their words before that example:

> Some people find it less awkward to carry along two sequences of
>   matrices, one describing the reduction of $A$ to the identity and the
>   other recording the effect of the same sequence of operations starting
>   from the identity.

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46862/prove-that-a-matrix-is-invertible), Adrián Barquero says:

> If your linear algebra textbook is Kenneth Hoffmann and Ray Kunze's
>   Linear Algebra book then I was in the same situation you're right now
>   a few years ago, but I was adviced at the moment that this particular
>   exercise wasn't as easy as one might expect at first.
>
> The matrix you have is called the Hilbert matrix and the question you
>   have was already asked a couple of times in math overflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47561/deriving-inverse-of-hilbert-matrix) and
>   [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60000/elementary-proof-that-the-hilbert-matrix-is-invertible-with-integer-entries-clos). They have excellent answers so I will just point you to them.

My question: Is it possible answer the question made by the authors without using high techniques?  I am not allowed to use determinants here.

PS: Those answers in MO don't answer the question above. I apologise if this question is unappropriated or if I was unable to understand their answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I believe a student at the level of this book is able to answer the question. But this is not easy. I think it would be an issue at the Mathematical Olympiad.

I suggest you do this proof by induction on the size $n$ of the $n \times n$ Hilbert matrix $A_n.$ Start the induction step with $n = 2 $ . The statement is essentially the following:

$$
 A_n = \left(\frac{1}{i + j-1}\right)_{ij} \mbox{ is a Hilbert matrix
}\Rightarrow A_n^{-1} \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{Z}).
 $$

Step 1. Verify that by inspection for $ n = 2 $.

Step 2. Verify that if $A_n$ is a Hilbert matrix, then
$$
A_{n+1}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
A_n & v^{T} \\
v   & \frac{1}{2(n+1)-1}
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
$$
is a Hilbert matrix with $v=\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\dots,\frac{1}{2(n+1)-2}\right)$. Now apply [matrix inversion in block form, special case 1.](http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/%7Ejang/book/addenda/matinv/matinv/)
And in this special case in which the blocks are matrices that commute, there is an exercise in the Hoffman book (do not remember which page).

**Edit 1.**
And in this particular case, this formula can be obtained using the definition of the inverse of a matrix. Just partition the inverse matrix into blocks of the same size and make the product and solve a matrix system. I believe that a student at the Mathematical Olympiad may have this idea, and an average student can understand it.

**Edit 2.** Done what was said in **Edit 1**, according to the notation of the link, just to verify that for $k =\frac{1}{2(n+1)-1} - vA_n^{-1}v^T,$ we have that $ \frac{1}{k}A_n^{-1}v^T \in\mathbb{Z} $. But this can be checked again by induction.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't follow your link because the server isn't reachable. However, if I do the calculation myself, I get your $k$ as the reciprocal of the bottom right entry of the inverse, so it seems we need not just $\frac{1}{k}A_n^{-1}v^T \in\mathbb{Z}$ but $\frac{1}{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$? I don't see how to show either of them by induction.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

Comment: That's a long article. What part of it do you think answers my comment?

Comment: @Joriki. It makes sense that you pointed out. But if not by induction we have to explicitly calculate the entries of the Shur complement as a function of $ 1, \dots, n $ which is the sum of a series of integers.

Comment: See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement  View the block inversion formula for  matrices and Shur complement formula.

Comment: Would you please add more detail showing that the blocks of $A_{n+1}^{-1}$ have integer entries.