# When the inverse of a matrix with integer entries also has integer entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A\in\Bbb{GL}_n(\Bbb R)$, (the space of all invertible matrices of order $n$), have integer entries.

If $\det(A)=\pm 1$ then obviously $A^{-1}$ have integer entries. Is the converse true, that is, if  $A^{-1}$ have integer entries does it imply that $\det(A)=\pm 1$?
Obviously for that $|\det(A)|=\gcd\{|A_{ij}|,1\leq i,j\leq n\}$ where $A_{ij}$ is the$(i,j)^{th}$ cofactor. But is it necessary for the $\gcd$ to be $1$ for a matrix to be invertible?

Comment: Just check hilbert matrix and its inverse. Inverse of hilbert matrix have integer entries but matrix is not itself integer matrix.It is rational entry matrix.

Comment: To refer to what maths student had already said, [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/112113/721644) and [explanation why the inverse of the Hilbert matrix has integer coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/430060/721644).

Comment: This is only true for n > 1 !

Comment: @jherek: No, it's not. If you think otherwise, please provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have integer entries, then
$$\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=\det(AA^{-1})=\det(I)=1$$
and as $\det(A)$ and $\det(A^{-1})$ are integers, then $\det(A)=\det(A^{-1})=\pm1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this $3 \times 3 $ matrix :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1/2 & 1/3 \\ 1/2 & 1/3 & 1/4 \\ 1/3 & 1/4 &1/5  \end{pmatrix} $$

It is easy to check that

$$A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}9 & -36 & 30 \\ -36 & 192 & -180 \\ 30 & -180 &180  \end{pmatrix} $$
But $\det(A)=\frac1{2160}$