# True or False: If $A$ is square and $|\det(A)|=1$, then $A^{-1}$ has integer entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> True or False: If $A$ is square and $|\det(A)|=1$, then $A^{-1}$ has integer entries.

I spent a good amount of time thinking about this problem. I think the answer would be false as I could see a possible counterexample. Could somebody please help me out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What field/ring is your matrix defined on?

Comment: Are the entries of $A$ integers? What are your thoughts on the possible counterexample?

Comment: Hint: Cramer's Rule

Comment: You need that $A$ is an integer matrix to conclude this.

Comment: a counterexample could be  (1/3, 1) for row 2 and (1,9) for row 2 det(A)=1 A^-1 : (9, -1) for row one and (-2, 1/3) for row 2

Comment: Well, depends, and take an identity for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When the inverse of a matrix with integer entries also have integer entries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521050/when-the-inverse-of-a-matrix-with-integer-entries-also-have-integer-entries)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** (I'm assuming $A$'s entries are integers.) Easy to see on a $2\times 2$ matrix. In general:

$$ A^{-1} = \det(A)^{-1} \mathrm{adj}(A) $$

(adjugate matrix description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix))