# How to prove the sum of all entries of the inverse of the Hilbert matrix with order n is $n^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-matrices

I have read all kinds of posts relative to Hilbert matrix such as 
[Why does the inverse of the Hilbert matrix have integer entries?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430060/why-does-the-inverse-of-the-hilbert-matrix-have-integer-entries)

[Prove that a matrix is invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46862/prove-that-a-matrix-is-invertible)

[Why does the inverse of the Hilbert matrix have integer entries?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430060/why-does-the-inverse-of-the-hilbert-matrix-have-integer-entries)

And recently I have encountered a problem relevant to  Hilbert matrix.The original version is as follows:
"Assume that $f\in C([0,1])$ and
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1f(x)d x=\int_0^1xf(x)dx=\cdots=\int_0^1x^{n-1}f(x)d x=1.
\end{align*},Prove that $\int_0^1\big(f(x)\big)^2 x\geqslant n^2$"

Actually this problem is equal to proving the sum of all entries of the inverse of the Hilbert matrix with order $n$ is no less than $n^2$.
And by observing the result that
\begin{align*}
H^{-1}_2=\begin{pmatrix}
4&-6\\
-6&12
\end{pmatrix},H^{-1}_3=\begin{pmatrix}
9&-36&30\\
-36&192&-180\\
30&-180&180
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
It's easy to see that the Hilbert matrix with order $n$($n=2,3$) is $n^2$.So I guess that It's true for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.Can anyone give an elementary proof to my question?

Comment: Since that sum is $\Bbb 1^t H^{-1} \Bbb 1$, where $\Bbb 1$ is the vector of all 1's, if you can write $\Bbb 1 = H q$ for some simple vector $q$, you can turn this into $\Bbb 1^t H^{-1} Hq = \Bbb 1^t q$, which is the sum of the entries of $q$.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Elements_in_Inverse_of_Hilbert_Matrix

Comment: Thanks to Jack,I have  refered to the book "The Art of Computer Programming: Volume 1"P36,and see the problem!Besides,at the end of this book it has offered an answer.Mainly it uses some property of Cauchy matrix which is a general case of Hilbert matrix.

Answer (score 2):

(Argument transcribed from my work on AoPS [here](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h146373p835508)). The original problem of that thread, from the 2006 Colombian olympiad, was exactly the "original version" you referenced here.

We will start all sums at zero; the rows and columns of our matrices are indexed by $\{0,1,\cdots,n-1\}$.

Using the inner product notation $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 fg$, we have that the $ik$ entry $\frac1{i+k+1}$ of the Hilbert matrix $H$ is $\langle x^{i},x^{k}\rangle.$ If $f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$ and $g(x)=b_{0}+b_{1}x+\cdots+b_{n-1}x^{n-1},$ this gives $\langle f,g\rangle=\sum_{i,k}a_{i}b_{k}h_{ik}=a^{T}Hb,$ where $a$ and $b$ are the column vectors of coefficients. Suppose $q$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ satisfying $\langle q,x^{k}\rangle=1$ for each $k,$ and let $a=(a_{0},a_{1},\dots,a_{n-1})^{T}$ be its coefficient vector in the standard basis. Our inner product relation becomes
$(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)\cdot H\cdot (a_{0},\dots,a_{k-1},a_{k},a_{k+1},\dots,a_{n-1})= 1$, or equivalently $I\cdot H\cdot\begin{pmatrix}a_{0}\\ a_{1}\\ \vdots\\ a_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ \vdots\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=j.$ (In all following computations, $j$ is this vector.)
Multiplying by $H^{-1}$, $a=H^{-1}j,$ and $\langle q,q\rangle=(H^{-1}j)^{T}H(H^{-1}j)=j^{T}H^{-1}j.$ For any matrix $M,$ $j^{T}Mj$ is the sum of the entries of $M$, and we have that the two versions of this problem are equivalent.

Now, we need to compute some details of $H^{-1}.$ To do this, we work with an orthonormal set of polynomials $p_i$, which are scaled Legendre polynomials. For each $k,$ $p_{k}(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2k+1}}{k!}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}(x-x^{2})^{k}.$ Orthogonality can be proven by integrating by parts repeatedly, differentiating the polynomial of lower degree and integrating the polynomial of higher degree; the boundary terms vanish at each step. The normalization constant also comes from an integration by parts: $\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}(x-x^{2})^{k}\right)^{2}\,dx=(2k)!\int_{0}^{1}x^{j}(1-x)^{j}\,dx,$ and this latter integral can be computed by integrating by parts another $j$ times.

Let $P$ be the upper triangular matrix with $ik$ entry the $x^{i}$ coefficient of $p_{k}.$ We have $P^{T}HP=\begin{pmatrix}\langle p_{0},p_{0}\rangle&\langle p_{0},p_{1}\rangle&\cdots&\langle p_{0},p_{n-1}\rangle\\ \langle p_{1},p_{0}\rangle&\langle p_{1},p_{1}\rangle&\cdots&\langle p_{1},p_{n-1}\rangle\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ \langle p_{n-1},p_{0}\rangle&\langle p_{n-1},p_{1}\rangle&\cdots&\langle p_{n-1},p_{n-1}\rangle\end{pmatrix}=I.$

Therefore, $H=(P^{T})^{-1}IP^{-1}=(PP^{T})^{-1},$ and $H^{-1}=PP^{T}.$ We get $j^{T}H^{-1}j=(j^{T}P)(P^{T}j)=\|P^{T}j\|^{2}.$ The $k$th entry of $P^{T}j$ is the sum of the entries in the $k$th column of $P,$ which is $p_{k}(1).$ By the symmetry of our definition, $p_{k}(1)=(-1)^{k}p_{k}(0)=(-1)^{k}\sqrt{2k+1}.$ Therefore, $j^{T}H^{-1}j=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2k+1=n^{2}$ and we have solved the problem.

That's not all, of course: we can get plenty of information on $H^{-1}$ from $P$. The upper left entry of $H^{-1}$ is the sum of the squares of the entries in the first row of $P;$ the $k$th entry in the first row is $p_{k}(0)=\sqrt{2k+1},$ and the upper left entry is also equal to $n^{2}.$
We can show that the entries of $H^{-1}$ are all integers: since $\frac1{k!}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}$ maps polynomials with integer coefficients to other polynomials with integer coefficients, $P=\begin{pmatrix}q_{0}&q_{1}&\cdots&q_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&0&\cdots&0\\ 0&\sqrt{3}&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ 0&0&\cdots&\sqrt{2n-1}\end{pmatrix},$ where each $q_{k}$ is an integer vector (which we will also interpret as the integer polynomial $\frac1{\sqrt{2k+1}}p_{k}$). This makes $PP^{T}=\begin{pmatrix}q_{0}&q_{1}&\cdots&q_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&0&\cdots&0\\ 0&3&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ 0&0&\cdots&2n-1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}q_{0}^{T}\\ q_{1}^{T}\\ \cdots\\ q_{n-1}^{T}\end{pmatrix},$ a product of integer matrices.
We can go a step further and write the exact entries of $H^{-1}$ as sums; $(x-x^{2})^{k}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{i}\binom{k}{i}x^{i+k},$ and $q_{k}(x)=\frac1{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{i}\binom{k}{i}\frac{(k+i)!}{i!}x^{i}= \sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{i}\binom{k}{i}\cdot\binom{k+i}{i}x^{i}.$ Let $(q_{k})_{i}$ be the coefficient of $x^{i}$ in $q_{k}.$
The $ik$ entry of $H^{-1}$ is then equal to $\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}(q_\ell)_{i}\cdot (2\ell+1)\cdot (q_\ell)_{k}=(-1)^{i+k}\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}(2\ell+1)\binom{\ell}{i}\cdot\binom{\ell}{k}\cdot\binom{\ell+i}{i}\cdot\binom{\ell+k}{k}.$ For many entries, most terms in this sum are zero. In an extreme case, the lower right entry of $H^{-1}$ has just one nonzero term in the sum; that entry is $(2n-1)\binom{2n-2}{n-1}^{2}.$

Since $P$ is triangular, the determinant of $H^{-1}$ is relatively easy to calculate; it's $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(2i+1)(q_{i})_{i}^{2}=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(2i+1)\binom{2i}{i}^{2}.$
If we write $\binom{2i}{i}=2^{2i}\cdot\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2i-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2i)},$ the determinant becomes $\det(H^{-1})$
$=2^{4+8+\cdots+(4n-4)}\cdot 1^{2n-1}\cdot 2^{-(2n-2)}\cdot 3^{2n-3}\cdot 4^{-(2n-4)}\cdots (2n-1)^{1}\cdot (2n)^{0}$
$=2^{2n^{2}-2n}\prod_{k=1}^{2n}k^{(-1)^{k+1}(2n-k)}.$